# Other language login details

Tags: php

I have a question regarding using login details such as this (國語注音符號第二式).

Is it possible to use symbols like this in username and password fields for a database?
Will the checks return true when comparing?

How would I go about making this possible?

Should I abandon this idea and try something else (numbers?).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can have that idea in your mind, everything is restricted to your database `collation`. You have to select the database `collation` carefully which is capable enough to handle your language from the front-end.

At the Server-Side, either it be `PHP` or any other language you can read it, if you are having problem reading it, which I dont think so that you would face, then read the data as `ASCII` value, so get a list of all the ASCII that you would accept.

That we you can do what is required. But I guess collation would work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just change character encoding in database and in php. If you use appropriate encoding, than all strings will be fine.